# Errors with Angular.Dart tutorials

Tags: angularjs, dart, angular-dart

Installed Google Dart 1.0. Basically a Dart noob at this point...

angular.dart tutorial apps at - https://github.com/angular/angular.dart.tutorial
Seems broken or I am doing something wrong.

in chapter folders, file `pubspec.yaml` contains text: `../pubspec.yaml` - which seems to be non yaml. 
pub errors out with

> Pub get failed, [1] Error in pubspec.yaml: The pubspec must be a YAML mapping.

There is a common pubspec.yaml in dir below chapter dirs, it contains legit yaml.

Even after editing chapter project pubspec.yaml with "common" pubspec legit yaml content and doing pub get, chapter 03..06 demos have missing package references.

Anyone who can tell me what I'm doing wrong appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

There is a bug with the tutorial on Windows: https://github.com/angular/angular.dart.tutorial/issues/8

which should be fixed soon.

Answer (score 0):

Having the same issue at present.
Short-term solution appears to not be to edit yaml files/links, (if you have, its probably best to re-download the tutorial files from fresh)
instead:
open the main.dart files in each affected example,
changes lines such as:

import 'package:angular_dart_demo/rating/rating_component.dart';

to

import '../lib/rating/rating_component.dart';

(you should see the ~ underlines disappear when you type this)

I think this has been due to some recent restructuring of the example files, since these were working until recently.